# ASP.NET User Interface Language selection

Tags: asp.net, web, multilingual

friends

I want to add three languages to my ASP.NET website to give users language options.How could I do this.If possible, could you explain it me in details?Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using the [Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms247246(v=vs.100).aspx).

And for setting/detecting current language in the views you can use cookies or the routing (which is more preferable due to it's SEO and cache friendly behavior). [Here](https://www.strathweb.com/2015/11/localized-routes-with-asp-net-5-and-mvc-6/) is a tutorial.